# Dynamically invoking any function by passing function name as string

Tags: c#, reflection, function, instance

How do I automate the process of getting an instance created and its function executed dynamically?

Thanks

Edit: Need an option to pass parameters too. Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Do you just want to call a parameterless constructor to create the instance? Is the type specified as a string as well, or can you make it a generic method? For example:

```
// All error checking omitted. In particular, check the results
// of Type.GetType, and make sure you call it with a fully qualified
// type name, including the assembly if it's not in mscorlib or
// the current assembly. The method has to be a public instance
// method with no parameters. (Use BindingFlags with GetMethod
// to change this.)
public void Invoke(string typeName, string methodName)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    method.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

or

```
public void Invoke<T>(string methodName) where T : new()
{
    T instance = new T();
    MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName);
    method.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

To invoke a constructor, [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) will do the trick.  It has a bunch of overloads to make your life easier.

If your constructor is [parameterless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

If you need [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx):

```
object instance =  Activator.CreateInstance(type, param1, param2)
```

To invoke, a method, once you have the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) object you can call [`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) to get the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx), and then [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx) (with or without parameters) to invoke it.  Should you need it, Invoke will also give you the return value of the function you're calling (or null if its a void method),

For a slightly more detailed sample (paste into a console app and go):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Invoker
    {
        public static object CreateAndInvoke(string typeName, object[] constructorArgs, string methodName, object[] methodArgs)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs);

            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
            return method.Invoke(instance, methodArgs);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Default constructor, void method
            Invoker.CreateAndInvoke("Test.Tester", null, "TestMethod", null);

            // Constructor that takes a parameter
            Invoker.CreateAndInvoke("Test.Tester", new[] { "constructorParam" }, "TestMethodUsingValueFromConstructorAndArgs", new object[] { "moo", false });

            // Constructor that takes a parameter, invokes a method with a return value
            string result = (string)Invoker.CreateAndInvoke("Test.Tester", new object[] { "constructorValue" }, "GetContstructorValue", null);
            Console.WriteLine("Expect [constructorValue], got:" + result);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        public string _testField;

        public Tester()
        {
        }

        public Tester(string arg)
        {
            _testField = arg;
        }

        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called TestMethod");
        }

        public void TestMethodWithArg(string arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called TestMethodWithArg: " + arg);
        }

        public void TestMethodUsingValueFromConstructorAndArgs(string arg, bool arg2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called TestMethodUsingValueFromConstructorAndArg " + arg + " " + arg2 + " " + _testField);
        }

        public string GetContstructorValue()
        {
            return _testField;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if there is no namespace how do we provide typeName

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the method you want to invoke does not take any parameters:

```
public void InvokeMethod(Type type, string methodName)
{
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

    method.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is little too generic here, I am providing a solution with certain assumptions here.

Assumption: you have a typeName (string), methodName (string), and a parameter (of SomeType).

```
public static void InvokeMethod(string typeName, string methodName, SomeType objSomeType) {
      Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
      if(type==null) {
        return;
      }
      object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); //Type must have a parameter-less contructor, or no contructor.   
      MethodInfo methodInfo =type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
      if(methodInfo==null) {
        return;
      }
      methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new[] { objSomeType });  
    }
```

let me know know if my assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To pass the parameters dynamically 
Here I have taken params string[] args, because different functions have different number of parameters so.

```
public void Invoke(string typeName,string functionName,params string[] args)
    {

     Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
     dynamic c=Activator.CreateInstance(type);
     //args contains the parameters(only string type)
     type.InvokeMember(functionName,BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,c,args);   

    }
```

Comment: Big +1 for the use of InvokeMember to get the correct method and invoke all in one.  If OP needs the MethodInfo, I think there are overrides for GetMethod that similarly take parameter types to get the best method.