# How can call method dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods, reflection, methodinfo

I have a class , and in this class i have many method and i wanna call all method with out write name

This is my code and it work :

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(content).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (System.Reflection.MethodInfo m in methods)
        {
            Response.Write(typeof(content).GetMethod(m.Name).Invoke(null,null).ToString());
}
```

But i have one problem ,that code return just first method name

What should I do to get all of them? what's wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one public static method?

Comment: Try Response.Write(m.Invoke(null,null).ToString());

Comment: Your invoke call doesn't include the object you are calling that method on. For example, if you look at the solution here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801070/dynamically-invoking-any-function-by-passing-function-name-as-string) it calls invoke on an object which is an instance of that type: `method.Invoke(instance, null);`.

Comment: @Alioza yeah i'm sure , i wrote `Response.Write(m.Name);` returned all method name

Comment: @Oleg : i did some thing you say  , but got some response again

Comment: @Alexandru i did some thing you say  , but got some response again

Comment: Does it return only one method and then exit normally or does it throw an exception or something?

Comment: @sirdank : my problem was resolved , thank's for question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke each method upon an instance.  In the below example, `.Invoke()` is called against an instance of `Content`.  That said, you're also making a redundant `GetMethod()` call.  You can use the `MethodInfo` directly.

```
void Main()
{
    var content = new Content();

    System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(Content).GetMethods(
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

    foreach (System.Reflection.MethodInfo m in methods)
    {
        Response.Write(m.Invoke(content, null).ToString());
    }
}

public class Content
{
    public static void Test1() {}
    public static void Test2() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are all the methods you want to execute `public` and `static`? Good. Now check to see if you are passing the correct parameters to each method you want to call.

`Invoke(null, null)` only works for methods accepting no parameters. If you try to call methods that require parameters using `.Invoke(null, null)`, an exception will be thrown.

For example, if you have two methods

```
public static void Example1() { ... }
public static void Example2(string example) { ... }
```

This code will run `Example1()`, print it out, and then crash when it tries to pass 0 parameters to `Example2()` To invoke `Example2()` you would need `.Invoke(null, new object[1])`